# Find a complete word in a string java

Tags: java

I am writing a piece of code in which i have to find only complete words for example if i have

```
String str = "today is tuesday";
```

and I'm searching for "t" then I should not find any word.

Can anybody tell how can I write such a program in java?

Comment: Do not delete questions when it's answered/solved. I've rollbacked it. If your problem is solved, then just comment or add an update and upvote helpful answers which helped in solving the problem and accept the answer which was the most helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use a regexps for such tasks. In your case it should look something like this:

```
String str = "today is tuesday";
return str.matches(".*?\\bt\\b.*?"); // returns "false"

String str = "today is t uesday";
return str.matches(".*?\\bt\\b.*?"); // returns "true"
```

A short explanation:

. matches any character, *? is for *zero or more times*, \b is a *word boundary*.

More information on regexps can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) or specifically for java [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @polygenelubricants: This will find words like "can't".

Comment: @bitschau: you're right, sorry. I got confused and thought you're splitting on `\b`.

Answer (score 5):

```
    String sentence = "Today is Tuesday";
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>(
        Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "))
    );
    System.out.println(words.contains("Tue")); // prints "false"
    System.out.println(words.contains("Tuesday")); // prints "true"
```

Each `contains(word)` query is `O(1)`, so short of implementing your own sophisticated dictionary data structure, this is the fastest most practical solution if you have many words to look for in a text.

This uses [`String.split`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to separate out the words from the sentence on the `" "` delimiter. Other possible variations, depending on how the problem is defined, is to use `\b`, the word boundary anchor. The problem is considerably more difficult if you must take every grammatical features of natural languages into consideration (e.g. `"can't"` is split by `\b` into `"can"` and `"t"`).

Case insensitivity can be easily introduced by using the traditional case normalization trick: split and hash `sentence.toLowerCase()` instead, and see if it `contains(word.toLowerCase())`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info -- Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- [Wikipedia -- String searching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm)
- [Wikipedia -- Patricia Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patricia_trie)

Comment: From http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (`add`, `remove`, `contains` and `size`), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets."

Comment: Why not just using regexps? I don't like the idea of this lot operations: To split it, put it in a List and convert it to a HashSet.

Comment: Note that this will be case sensitive and confused by punctuation though.

Comment: @Jorn: are you on heavy drugs today?  A hashset's whole point is **precisely** that it offers constant-time performance on operations like *contains(...)*, as stated in the Java doc btw but it's pretty much common wisdom: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science) (notice the part where they say that access on a hash table is on average O(1)).

Comment: @bitschnau, @Adrian: Believe me, I love regex. I'm just interpreting the question (which is ill-defined) one way over another. In my interpretation, words are case sensitive, and are simply strings separated by space, and there will be multiple queries for words that aren't known in advance.

Comment: Note that my interpretation is by no means unique. ryanprayogo answers each query in `O(N)`. Bozho has an `O(N log N)` setup, and answers each subsequent query in `O(log N)`. I simply followed in their steps and improved the performance to `O(N)` setup and `O(1)` per query.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: The split()-operation uses a regexp operation to split the string, therefore it depends on the requirement which solution is better. If you do just one specific search, I would use regexps. Your solution is more flexibel at a higher cost of memory and runtime in the beginning. Though it will still be confused by punctation, which you must handle in a general case-handling like yours.

Comment: As a bonus: `\p{Space}` splits on newlines and tabs as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] tokens = str.split(" ");

for(String s: tokens) {
    if ("t".equals(s)) {
        // t exists
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
Arrays.sort(words);
Arrays.binarySearch(words, searchedFor);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "today is tuesday";

StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);

bool exists = false;

while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
    if (stringTokenizer.nextToken().equals("t")) {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."

Answer (score 1):

use a regex like "\bt\b".

Comment: This will not work for two reasons:

1. You have to escape the \, therefore write \\b
2. The matches()-method only matches whole strings, so you have to add wildcards, which leads to:

".*?\\bt\\b.*?"

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by putting a regex which should end with a space.

Comment: can you please write down the regex?

Comment: Won't that find words ending in t too?

Comment: better, use the word boundary pattern, as in my example (e.g. a word at the end of a sentence is not followed by a space).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the ["split"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) functionality for String with spaces as separators, then go through these elements one by one and make a direct comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this regex pattern1 = ".*\bt\b.*" instead of pattern2 = ".*?\bt\b.*?" . Pattern1 will help you to match the complete String if 't' occurs in that string rather than the pattern2 which just reaches the string "t" you are searching for and ignores rest of the string. There is not much difference in two approaches and for your particular use case of returning true/false will run fine both the ways. The one I suggested will help you to improvise the regex in case you make further changes in your use case