# Java: Finding the number of word matches in a given string

Tags: java, string, search

I am trying to find the number of **word matches** for a given string and keyword combination, like this:

```
public int matches(String keyword, String text){
 // ...
}
```

**Example:**

Given the following calls:

```
System.out.println(matches("t", "Today is really great, isn't that GREAT?"));
System.out.println(matches("great", "Today is really great, isn't that GREAT?"));
```

The result should be:

```
0
2
```

So far I found this: [Find a complete word in a string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765482/find-a-complete-word-in-a-string-java)

This only returns **if** the given keyword exists but not **how many** occurrences. Also, I am not sure if it ignores **case sensitivity** (which is important for me).

Remember that substrings should be ignored! I only want **full words** to be found.

---

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention that I also want keywords that are separated via whitespace to match.

E.g.

```
matches("today is", "Today is really great, isn't that GREAT?")
```

should return 1

Comment: Have a look at the `indexOf(...)` method in `java.lang.String`.  It does everything you need.

Comment: text.indexOf(keyword) returns the POSITION of keyword in text. What I need is the number of occurrences.

Comment: yes, and by taking the index of <search> in the substring starting from the prior position you can very easily count the number of instances of your search string in your source string!

Comment: Hm, good idea but I don't think that's very performant. Maybe a regex would be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression with word boundaries.  It's by far the easiest choice.

```
  int matches = 0;  
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bgreat\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(text);
  while (matcher.find()) matches++;
```

Your milage may vary on some foreign languages though.

Comment: Will that also work with white-space separated keywords? E.g. `Pattern.compile("\\btoday is\\b").matcher(text);`

Comment: @valmar: It can also match `Great` if you set it to case insensitive.

Comment: @valmar, it doesn't work as `isn't`, when you do a match on `t`, it finds the last `t` as a match.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I suppose you could use a different regex to ignore those characters, but then the question becomes: what do you define as a word; would you like it to generate a match for 'not' on `isn't`? That's a whole different level then :)

Answer (score 2):

How about taking advantage of indexOf ?

```
s1 = s1.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
s2 = s2.toLowerCase(Locale.US);
int count = 0;
int x;
int y = s2.length();
while((x=s1.indexOf(s2)) != -1){
   count++;
   s1 = s1.substr(x,x+y);
}
return count;
```

Efficient version

```
    int count = 0;
    int y = s2.length();
    for(int i=0; i<=s1.length()-y; i++){
       int lettersMatched = 0;
       int j=0; 
       while(s1[i]==s2[j]){
           j++;
           i++; 
           lettersMatched++;
       }
       if(lettersMatched == y) count++;
    }   
    return count;
```

For more efficient solution, you will have to modify KMP algorithm a little. Just google it, its simple.

Comment: Well, the second one is hard to beat. If you are that concerned about performance, do a comparison between that and, for instance, a regexp-based one. Regular expression matching is not inexpensive either, in terms of clock-cycles.

Answer (score 0):

well,you can use "split" to separate the words and find if there exists a word matches exactly.
hope that helps!

Comment: I forgot the mention that I also want keywords that are separated via whitespace to match. E.g. matches("today is", "Today is really great, isn't that GREAT?") should return 1.

Answer (score 0):

one option would be RegEx.  Basically it sounds like you are looking to match a word with any punctuation on the left or right.  so:

" great."
" great!"
" great "
" great,"
"Great"

would all match, but

"greatest"

wouldn't

Comment: I would want "Great" to match as well.
Also, white-space separated keywords should match as well. E.g. `matches("today is", "Today is really great, isn't that GREAT?")` should return 1.
Got a proposal for a working RegEx? I am really not an expert for that..