# Find word from some text on Java

Tags: java

Tell me please, how to find a word in the big text, beginning with the first letter and which consist of all it letters. If I have a text:

```
String str = "Hello my friend. How are you? I have a news………………….."
```

And I will put in search for example "ello" or "frie", then it should’nt find the words of the text. Only if fully enter in search "Hello" or "friend " or “news”

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Complete words are seperated with whitespaces. Incomplete words have at least one non whitepsace or non-alphabetic character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of the one linked below. The agreed upon answer was to use regex to test your matches. 
[Find a complete word in a string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765482/find-a-complete-word-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use [regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions, which are part of the java API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html