# How to find a Specific word in a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I´m doing a project for school and I need my method to return true only to a certain word.
This is what I have:

```
public boolean scanDescription (String keyword) {
    if (description.contains(keyword)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

So for example, if the keyword is "disk", I need this method to return true only when a string contains the word "disk", but my problem is that it returns true when a string contains words like "diskette"

PS.: I have also tried to use .indexOf and it did not work

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase()  works if it is a case insensitive match and equals() for a case sensitive search

Comment: This will show you the hints for your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a complete word in a string java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765482/find-a-complete-word-in-a-string-java)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the word boundary.

```
public boolean scanDescription(String keyword) {
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b"+keyword+"\\b");
     return pattern.matcher(description).find();
}
```

Comment: Can't I use just regex to find out the particular word in a string ??

Comment: @Vishwa It's what exactly the code doing.